# Errors compiling Boost segment_utils.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, boost-polygon

I would like to use the intersect_segments method of the Boost segment utils, which can be found here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/polygon/doc/gtl_segment_concept.htm

I also have followed and implemented the code that maps the Point and Segment structs to the Boost.Polygon concepts: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/polygon/doc/voronoi_basic_tutorial.htm

However, when I include `<boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp>` I get many errors during compiling:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:16:0,
         from test.cpp:17:
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:17:49: error: expected template-name before '<' token
   class line_intersection : public scanline_base<Unit> {
                         ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:17:49: error: expected '{' before '<' token
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:17:49: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:16:0,
         from test.cpp:17:
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:947:40: error: expected template-name before '<' token
   class scanline : public scanline_base<Unit> {
                    ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:947:40: error: expected '{' before '<' token
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:947:40: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1472:22: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'scanline_base'
     typedef typename scanline_base<Unit>::half_edge half_edge;
              ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1472:22: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1472:35: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
     typedef typename scanline_base<Unit>::half_edge half_edge;
                   ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1475:48: error: 'half_edge' does not name a type
     void operator()(result_type& result, const half_edge& edge, const key_type& left, const key_type& right) {
                        ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp: In member function 'void boost::polygon::merge_output_functor<Unit>::operator()(result_type&, const int&, const key_type&, const key_type&)':
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1476:26: error: 'half_edge' was not declared in this scope
       typename std::pair<half_edge, int> elem;
              ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1476:40: error: template argument 1 is invalid
       typename std::pair<half_edge, int> elem;
                    ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1476:42: error: 'elem' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
       typename std::pair<half_edge, int> elem;
                      ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1477:7: error: 'elem' was not declared in this scope
       elem.first = edge;
       ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1479:15: error: request for member 'second' in 'edge', which is of non-class type 'const int'
       if(edge.second < edge.first) elem.second *= -1;
           ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1479:29: error: request for member 'first' in 'edge', which is of non-class type 'const int'
       if(edge.second < edge.first) elem.second *= -1;
                 ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1480:10: error: 'boost::polygon::merge_output_functor<Unit>::scanline_base {aka int}' is not a template
       if(scanline_base<Unit>::is_vertical(edge)) elem.second *= -1;
      ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1480:10: error: 'scanline_base' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp: At global scope:
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1491:46: error: expected template-name before '<' token
   class property_merge : public scanline_base<Unit> {
                          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1491:46: error: expected '{' before '<' token
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:1491:46: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:16:0,
         from test.cpp:17:
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2490:52: error: expected template-name before '<' token
   class arbitrary_boolean_op : public scanline_base<Unit> {
                            ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2490:52: error: expected '{' before '<' token
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2490:52: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp: In function 'bool boost::polygon::test_arbitrary_boolean_op(stream_type&)':
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2653:5: error: 'polygon_set_data' was not declared in this scope
     polygon_set_data<Unit> psd;
     ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2653:26: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
     polygon_set_data<Unit> psd;
              ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2653:28: error: 'psd' was not declared in this scope
     polygon_set_data<Unit> psd;
                ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2657:26: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
     polygon_set_data<Unit> psd2;
              ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2657:28: error: 'psd2' was not declared in this scope
     polygon_set_data<Unit> psd2;
                ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2660:17: error: 'polygon_data' was not declared in this scope
     std::vector<polygon_data<Unit> > pv;
         ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2660:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     std::vector<polygon_data<Unit> > pv;
                  ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2660:34: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2660:36: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
     std::vector<polygon_data<Unit> > pv;
                    ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2661:5: error: 'pv' was not declared in this scope
     pv.clear();
     ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2663:26: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
     polygon_set_data<Unit> psd3;
              ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2663:28: error: 'psd3' was not declared in this scope
     polygon_set_data<Unit> psd3;
                ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp: At global scope:
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2710:65: error: expected template-name before '<' token
   class arbitrary_connectivity_extraction : public scanline_base<Unit> {
                                 ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2710:65: error: expected '{' before '<' token
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:2710:65: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
In file included from test.cpp:17:0:
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp: In function 'typename boost::enable_if<typename boost::polygon::gtl_and<typename boost::polygon::gtl_if<typename boost::polygon::is_segment_concept<typename boost::polygon::geometry_concept<typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator1>::value_type>::type>::type>::type, typename boost::polygon::gtl_if<typename boost::polygon::is_segment_concept<typename boost::polygon::geometry_concept<GeometryType>::type>::type>::type>::type, void>::type boost::polygon::intersect_segments(std::vector<std::pair<long unsigned int, Segment> >&, SegmentIterator, SegmentIterator)':
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:46:20: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'scanline_base'
   typedef typename scanline_base<Unit>::Point Point;
            ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:46:33: error: expected initializer before '<' token
   typedef typename scanline_base<Unit>::Point Point;
                 ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:47:20: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'scanline_base'
   typedef typename scanline_base<Unit>::half_edge half_edge;
            ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:47:33: error: expected initializer before '<' token
   typedef typename scanline_base<Unit>::half_edge half_edge;
                 ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:49:25: error: 'half_edge' was not declared in this scope
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges;
             ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:49:46: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges;
                          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:49:48: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges;
                        ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:49:48: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:50:25: error: the value of 'half_edge' is not usable in a constant expression
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges_out;
             ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:49:25: note: 'half_edge' was not declared 'constexpr'
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges;
             ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:50:46: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair'
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges_out;
                          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:50:46: note:   expected a type, got 'half_edge'
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:50:48: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges_out;
                        ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:50:48: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:52:14: error: request for member 'reserve' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
   half_edges.reserve(std::distance(first, last));
          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:57:16: error: request for member 'push_back' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
     half_edges.push_back(std::make_pair(half_edge(l, h), id_in++));
        ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:59:18: error: request for member 'reserve' in 'half_edges_out', which is of non-class type 'int'
   half_edges_out.reserve(half_edges.size());
          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:59:37: error: request for member 'size' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
   half_edges_out.reserve(half_edges.size());
                     ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:61:18: error: request for member 'size' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
   if (half_edges.size() != 0) {
          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:63:36: error: request for member 'begin' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
     half_edges_out, half_edges.begin(), half_edges.end());
                    ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:63:56: error: request for member 'end' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
     half_edges_out, half_edges.begin(), half_edges.end());
                            ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:66:49: error: request for member 'size' in 'half_edges_out', which is of non-class type 'int'
   result.reserve(result.size() + half_edges_out.size());
                         ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:67:46: error: request for member 'size' in 'half_edges_out', which is of non-class type 'int'
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < half_edges_out.size(); ++i) {
                          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:68:52: error: invalid types 'int[std::size_t {aka long unsigned int}]' for array subscript
     std::size_t id = (std::size_t)(half_edges_out[i].second);
                            ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:69:31: error: invalid types 'int[std::size_t {aka long unsigned int}]' for array subscript
     Point l = half_edges_out[i].first.first;
                   ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:70:31: error: invalid types 'int[std::size_t {aka long unsigned int}]' for array subscript
     Point h = half_edges_out[i].first.second;
                   ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp: In function 'typename boost::enable_if<typename boost::polygon::gtl_and<typename boost::polygon::gtl_if<typename boost::polygon::is_segment_concept<typename boost::polygon::geometry_concept<typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator1>::value_type>::type>::type>::type, typename boost::polygon::gtl_if<typename boost::polygon::is_segment_concept<typename boost::polygon::geometry_concept<typename SegmentContainer::value_type>::type>::type>::type>::type, void>::type boost::polygon::intersect_segments(SegmentContainer&, SegmentIterator, SegmentIterator)':
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:101:20: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'scanline_base'
   typedef typename scanline_base<Unit>::Point Point;
            ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:101:33: error: expected initializer before '<' token
   typedef typename scanline_base<Unit>::Point Point;
                 ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:102:20: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'scanline_base'
   typedef typename scanline_base<Unit>::half_edge half_edge;
            ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:102:33: error: expected initializer before '<' token
   typedef typename scanline_base<Unit>::half_edge half_edge;
                 ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:104:25: error: 'half_edge' was not declared in this scope
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges;
             ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:104:46: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges;
                          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:104:48: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges;
                        ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:104:48: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:105:25: error: the value of 'half_edge' is not usable in a constant expression
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges_out;
             ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:104:25: note: 'half_edge' was not declared 'constexpr'
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges;
             ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:105:46: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair'
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges_out;
                          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:105:46: note:   expected a type, got 'half_edge'
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:105:48: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   std::vector<std::pair<half_edge, segment_id> > half_edges_out;
                        ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:105:48: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:107:14: error: request for member 'reserve' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
   half_edges.reserve(std::distance(first, last));
          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:112:16: error: request for member 'push_back' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
     half_edges.push_back(std::make_pair(half_edge(l, h), id_in++));
        ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:114:18: error: request for member 'reserve' in 'half_edges_out', which is of non-class type 'int'
   half_edges_out.reserve(half_edges.size());
          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:114:37: error: request for member 'size' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
   half_edges_out.reserve(half_edges.size());
                     ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:116:18: error: request for member 'size' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
   if (half_edges.size() != 0) {
          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:118:36: error: request for member 'begin' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
     half_edges_out, half_edges.begin(), half_edges.end());
                    ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:118:56: error: request for member 'end' in 'half_edges', which is of non-class type 'int'
     half_edges_out, half_edges.begin(), half_edges.end());
                            ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:121:49: error: request for member 'size' in 'half_edges_out', which is of non-class type 'int'
   result.reserve(result.size() + half_edges_out.size());
                         ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:122:46: error: request for member 'size' in 'half_edges_out', which is of non-class type 'int'
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < half_edges_out.size(); ++i) {
                          ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:123:31: error: invalid types 'int[std::size_t {aka long unsigned int}]' for array subscript
     Point l = half_edges_out[i].first.first;
                   ^
/usr/include/boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp:124:31: error: invalid types 'int[std::size_t {aka long unsigned int}]' for array subscript
     Point h = half_edges_out[i].first.second;
```

Could this mean that I need to implement the Unit concept as well? If so, how is that done?

Edit: My code is the same as this code: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/polygon/example/voronoi_basic_tutorial.cpp but then with `#include <boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp>` added.

Comment: Can we see complete code?

Comment: I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>` before including `<boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/scan_arbitrary.hpp:17:49: error: expected template-name before '<' token
   class line_intersection : public scanline_base<Unit> {
                         ^
```

This error suggests you've defined `line_intersection` as a macro, because it's complaining about a `<` token where there isn't one in the source.

But since you haven't shown any code, we can't tell.

**Edit after updated question:**

This seems to be a a Boost bug, it can be reproduced with a file consisting of nothing but:

```
#include <boost/polygon/segment_utils.hpp>
```

Comment: The ^ characters did not copy correctly, the ^ should be just before Unit

Comment: I don't think it is bug, it's just the way Boost is developed.

Comment: Well I've reported it as a bug: https://github.com/boostorg/polygon/issues/18 -- it's not a "detail" header, so should be includable, or it should complain that the necessary header wasn't included first. The errors it gives now are unclear and unhelpful. I call that a bug.